# Way of counting words in a string

Tags: javascript, count, cpu-word

I just need a function for counting a given word in a string.
There is something that has to do with split but I cant get what I should do from then.
Thank u for your time.

PS I forgot to mention. My apologies. I want to do that with javascript.

Comment: In what programming language do you want to do this?

Comment: Lets say this string: "dog, cat, horse, cat, bird, cat, horse, bird, dog"
How many times each animal appears in that string?

Comment: just look at to the link i have provided.Its exactly that you need

Comment: Thank u all for yr answers. I think bilash.saha provided me the code I need. Im going to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't know in which programming language you want to do this.

Here is a nice example of [Word counting with frequency of occurrence in Javascript](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Language-Basics/Stringutilitywordcountreplaceandcapitalize.htm).

You can take a look what its doing by clicking 'Try this example' button.

There is word count, replace and capitalize.You just need the wordCount() function.

Answer (score 0):

After splitting by the word, just take the length of the resulting array and subtract one.

What programming language are you doing this in?

Comment: I think its counting 'a given word' in a string , not the number of word in the string.

Comment: @bilash.saha: Missed the *given*. Corrected.